# Sending certain logs to a remote syslog-ng server

Tags: syslog-ng

I am unable to send `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to remote server.

I have tried below methods but no luck.

After done below configuration am not able to restart the `syslog-ng` service.

`syslog-ng` version is `syslog-ng-1.6.8-20.21.1` in `sles10`.

method1 :

```
source s_auditlog {pipe(“/var/log/audit/audit.log);};
destination d_audit_access { file(“/var/log/audit/$FULLHOST” template(“$MSGONLYn”) template-escape(no) owner(“root”) group(“root”) perm(0640));};
destination d_host { udp("10.253.1.231" port (514)); };
log {source(s_auditlog); destination(d_host); };
```

method2 :

```
source auditlog { file("/var/log/audit/audit.log" log_prefix("audit: "); };
destination d_host { udp("10.253.1.231" port (514)); };
log{ source(auditlog); destination(d_host); };
```

Comment: Method 1 will not work since /var/log/audit/audit.log is probably a file, not a named pipe.  In Method 2 you have unbalanced parentheses on the first line.

Comment: Thanks for the response. i have added brackets as below ---
 source auditlog { file ( "/var/log/audit/audit.log" ) log_prefix("audit: "); };

but still service is failing

Re-Starting syslog servicessyntax error at 199
Parse error reading configuration file, exiting. (line 199)
startproc:  exit status of parent of /sbin/syslog-ng: 1
                                                                      failed

Comment: This error message is very clear - syslog-ng was unable to parse line 199 of your config. Look at line 199 and compare it to the grammar of the config file.

Comment: Is it really /var/log/audit/audit.log you want to send on, or is it the information that ends up in that log?

Comment: I need to send only /var/log/audit/audit.log